# addEventListener doesn't work in IE (tested in IE8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, addeventlistener

Work in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/some/66nLy/)
I have tried solution from [here](http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/ie8-addeventlistener-alternative-example/) but doesn't help.

```
    if(window.attachEvent){
    // Attach event code here   
    window.attachEvent("load", toolify);
}
else{
    // Addeventlistener code here
    window.addEventListener('load',toolify,false);
}
```

Error from IE:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Sat, 23 Nov 2013 08:10:42 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <script>


    "use strict";
function click(event) {
  var elem = this.parentNode.querySelector('div.info_container');
  if (elem) elem.style.display = elem.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
function toolify() {
  var idx,
      len,
      elem,
      info,
      text,
      elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.tooltip'),
      canvas,
      imgurl,
      pointer,
      tipHeight = 20,
      tipWidth = 20,
      width = 200,
      height = 100,
      ctx;

  // Create a canvas element where the triangle will be drawn
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = tipHeight;
  canvas.height = tipWidth;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';   // Border color
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';     // background color
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  ctx.translate(-0.5,-0.5);   // Move half pixel to make sharp lines
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(1,canvas.height);              // lower left corner
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 1);              // upper right corner
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height);   // lower right corner
  ctx.fill();                               // fill the background
  ctx.stroke();                             // stroke it with border
  //fix bottom row
  ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height-0.5,canvas.width-1,canvas.height+2);

  // Create a div element where the triangel will be set as background
  pointer = document.createElement('div');
  pointer.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
  pointer.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';
  pointer.innerHTML = '&nbsp;' // non breaking space
  pointer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + canvas.toDataURL() + ')';
  pointer.style.position = 'absolute';
  pointer.style.top = '2px';
  pointer.style.right = '1px';
  pointer.style.zIndex = '1'; // place it over the other elements

  for (idx=0, len=elements.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
    elem = elements[idx];
    elem.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click',click);
    text = elem.querySelector('div.info');
    // Create a new div element, and place the text and pointer in it
    info = document.createElement('div');
    text.parentNode.replaceChild(info,text);
    info.className = 'info_container';
    info.appendChild(pointer.cloneNode());
    info.appendChild(text);
    //info.addEventListener('click',click);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load',toolify);
    </script>
    <style>
    div.tooltip
{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:300px;
  text-align:right;
}
div.tooltip > div.info
{
  display:none;
}
div.tooltip div.info_container
{
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  display:none;
}
div.tooltip div.info
{
  text-align:left;
  position:absolute;
  left:1px;
  right:1px;
  top:20px;
  bottom:1px;
  color:#000;
  padding:5px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

    </style>
</head>

    <body>
        <div class='tooltip'>
  <img src='http://www.craiglotter.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/craig_question_mark_icon1.png' alt='Help'/>
  <div class='info'>
    Some text to fill the box with.
  </div>
</div>
<div class='tooltip'>
  <img src='http://www.craiglotter.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/craig_question_mark_icon1.png' alt='Help'/>
  <div class='info'>
    Some text to fill the box with.   
  </div>
</div>

    </body>

<html>
```

Comment: IE8 uses attachEvent, others addEventLister. You test for one but still use the other?

Comment: I have updated but still doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

In IE, the event name is "onload", in W3C compliant browsers it's "load", so:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', ...);

} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', ...);
}
```

A better function for adding listeners in IE8 is below. It sets *this* to the element and passes *event* as the first parameter when using *attachEvent* to be more like *addEventListener*. It's not a full replacement for *addEventListener*, but there's an attempt at one on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). I'm not endorsing the function there (I think it will fail miserably in IE 7 and lower), just pointing it out as there is some good information in the article.

```
  function addListener(element, event, fn) {

    // Use addEventListener if available
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);

    // Otherwise use attachEvent, set this and event
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
      element.attachEvent('on' + event, (function (el) {
        return function() {
          fn.call(el, window.event);
        };
      }(element)));

      // Break closure and primary circular reference to element
      element = null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to do a little research first. W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) clearly gives the answer:

> Allows the registration of event listeners on the event target (IE8 =
>   attachEvent())

For knowing which one to use, just use a simple if statement

```
if(obj.attachEvent){
    // Attach event code here
}
else{
    // Addeventlistener code here
}
```

Comment: I have updated question based on your answer. But it still doesn't work in IE did I do something wrong?

Comment: @1110 Not sure. Can you put together a JS fiddle, or, if it's already online, give me that link?

Comment: @1110 - you're still using `.addEventListener` in both blocks.. (use .attachEvent in the IE one)

Comment: @enhzflep Wow, surprised I missed that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qAqZK/    just last line in script change with: if(window.attachEvent){
    // Attach event code here 
 window.attachEvent("load", toolify);
}
else{
    // Addeventlistener code here
 window.addEventListener('load',toolify,false);
}

Comment: No error for me if I change that last line, but I can't figure out what is supposed to be happening when it does work.

Comment: When you click on image tooltip should be shown bellow image

Comment: And your making those with a canvas?

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, it looks like all your JS is tied into the canvas, which IE8 doesn't support, as that is HTML5. There's where your problem is.